# Connecting to ERCOT web services using WSE 2.0

Tags: .net, wse2.0

I have been trying to setup a WSE 2.0 client for communicating with ERCOT and are stuck in the policy setup stage. We set up our environment using VS2005 with WSE 2.0 and have followed the slides (50 to 63) presented by ERCOT in the technical communications workshop, held in 2008 ([slides link](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/45550276/ERCOT-Technical-Communications-Workshop-Follow-Up-Meeting-communications_workshop_20080903_v3)).

After doing everything according to their slides, I am getting the following error from the server:

```
WSE405: A satisfactory subset of policy assertions that could be enforced for the outgoing message could not be found.
```

It will be awesome if you could please direct me towards the solution?